# web - Combo box selection and jquery

Tags: html, combobox

```
<div id="1">
<select id="combobox1">
 <option value="">mark this</option>
 <option value="green">long</option>
 <option value="blue">normal</option>     
</select>

<select id="combobox2">
 <option value="">mark this</option>
 <option value="green">long</option>
 <option value="blue">normal</option>     
</select>
</div>

<div id="2">
<span id="span1" >hello world</span>
<span id="span2" >good morning</span>
</div>

<div id="3">
</div>
<div id="4">
</div>
```

I want to add add a background color to span tag based on the selection of the combo box.

"combobox1" is for "span1" and "combobox2" is for "span2".
when changing the color should add an anchor tag with the href "#[id of the span tag]" inside "div3".

thank you for the answer below.

"I need to get the id and value auto."

```
$('#combobox1').change(function() {
$('#span1').css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
$('#div3').html('<a href="#span1">span1</a>');
});
```

At here (above is answer 1 from a stackoverflow user) ID of the combo box is defined. what will happen if the id is not static? a dynamic ID??? In my case there are several text boxes and combo boxes. There is no issue with span tags.

I need to  get the ID and the VALUE auto without predefining them as above.

Comment: What solution are you planning on using, JavaScript, jQuery, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a `change` event handler to each combobox:

```
$('#combobox1').change(function() {
    $('#span1').css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
    $('#div3').html('<a href="#span1">span1</a>');
});

$('#combobox2').change(function() {
    $('#span2').css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
    $('#div3').html('<a href="#span2">span2</a>');
});
```

Comment: Thank You very much....
<br>
ID of the combo box is defined. what will happen if the id is not static? a dynamic ID??? In my case there are several text boxes and combo boxes. There is no issue with span tags.

I need to get the ID and the VALUE auto without predefining them as above.